# How to modify spark source code and build

Tags: apache-spark

I just start learning spark. I have imported spark source code to IDEA and made some small changes (just add some println()) to spark source code. What should I do to see these updates? Should I recompile the spark? Thanks!

Comment: yes, you should recompile it.

Comment: You can follow this link : https://github.com/juanrh/devops/wiki/Compiling-and-developing-with-the-Spark-source

Answer (score 2):

At the bare minimum, you will need maven 3.3.3 and Java 7+.

You can follow the steps at http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html

The "make-distribution.sh" script is quite handy which comes within the spark source code root directory. This script will produce a distributable tar.gz which you can simply extract and launch spark-shell or spark-submit. After making the source code changes in spark, you can run this script with the right options (mainly passing the desired hadoop version, yarn or hive support options but these are required if you want to run on top of hadoop distro, or want to connect to existing hive).

BTW, inserting println() will not be a good idea as it can severely slow down the performance of the job. You should use a logger instead.